# backbonejs fetch returns twice (fail, then success)

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I am calling my api which returns a task object via json (example return json below):

```
[{"pkTaskId":"96","fldName":"Change page to template","fldStatus":"Assigned","fldNotes":"http:\/\/williamsconcepts.com\/ci\/codeigniter\/libraries\/template\/reference.html\r\n\r\n111","fldDateDue":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","fldDateCompleted":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pkTaskId":"103","fldName":"fix list creation","fldStatus":"Assigned","fldNotes":"for some reason there is an SQL syntax error\r\n\r\nok","fldDateDue":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","fldDateCompleted":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pkTaskId":"104","fldName":"navicat db admin tool","fldStatus":"Assigned","fldNotes":"Try this out:\nhttp:\/\/www.navicat.com\/download\/download.html","fldDateDue":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","fldDateCompleted":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pkTaskId":"105","fldName":"Styling dropdowns","fldStatus":"Assigned","fldNotes":"Link:\nhttp:\/\/jqueryui.com\/demos\/autocomplete\/#combobox","fldDateDue":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","fldDateCompleted":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pkTaskId":"147","fldName":"api create task","fldStatus":"Assigned","fldNotes":"","fldDateDue":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","fldDateCompleted":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]



    $(function(){
    window.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    window.TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Task,
        url: "http://localhost/tasker/index.php/api/tasks/username/lucasmp"
    });

    window.tasks = new TaskList();

    window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            tasks.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log(tasks.toJSON());
                }
            });   
        }
    });

    window.App = new AppView;    
});

$('#fetch').click(function(){
    tasks.fetch({
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
            console.log(tasks.toJSON());
        },
        error: alert("error")
    });    
});
```

I'm having an issue though with my fetch.click occurring twice; Once returns fetch error, then returns fetch success. What could be causing this to be fired twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try this

```
error: function(){alert("error")}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. His question is why it sends two requests. One failing the other succeeding.